# JavaScript variable to SQL

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a PHP page that gets a PHP variable from a previous page to convert hh:mm to seconds. Then I get the JS variable to a PHP variable, all on the same page along with many other variables to insert into DB. The problem is when I do the SQL query to save it to the DB the value stored is '0'. If I echo the PHP variable I get the supposed value. Example:

```
<script>
    var hms = '<?php echo $_POST['ptimeflown'];?>';
    var a = hms.split(':');
    var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60;
</script>

$ptimeflown = "<script>document.writeln(seconds);</script>";
```

Imagine that the time is 01:00.

If I `echo $ptimeflown;` I get "3600", but if I store that variable to DB using `mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO pendingflights (hoursflown) VALUES ('$ptimeflown');");` I get the value '0' at the DB.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: All code included.

```
<script>
    var hms = '<?php echo $_POST['ptimeflown'];?>';
    var a = hms.split(':');
    var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60; 
</script>

<?php

include "../config.php";

$pcallsign = $_POST['pcallsign'];
$pflight_number = $_POST['pflightnumber'];
$paircraft_reg = $_POST['paircraft_reg'];
$pdeparture = $_POST['pdeparture'];
$pdestination = $_POST['pdestination'];
$ptimeflown = "<script>document.writeln(seconds);</script>";
$pdistance = $_POST['pdistance'];
$pdate = $_POST['pdate'];
$premarks = $_POST['premarks'];

$target_dir = "uploads/pireps/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["ptracker"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if (isset($_POST["send"])) {

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["ptracker"]["tmp_name"]);

    if ($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } elseif ($check !== true) {
        print "File error: not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } elseif (file_exists($target_file)) {
        print "File error: file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } elseif ($_FILES["ptracker"]["size"] > 1000000) {
        print "File error: your file is too large (max. 1MB).";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } elseif ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
        print "File error: only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        print "There was some error submitting this manual pirep. Please contact the IT department.";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ptracker"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
        print "The file ". htmlspecialchars(basename( $_FILES["ptracker"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
        mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO pendingflights (flight_number,callsign,departure,destination,fpm,distance,fuel_used,fuel_remaining,aircraft_reg,datetime,hoursflown,tracker_image,remarks,mp)
                              VALUES ('$pflight_number','$pcallsign','$pdeparture','$pdestination','0','$pdistance','0','0','$paircraft_reg','$pdate','$ptimeflown','$target_file','$premarks','1');");
        mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM bookedflights WHERE callsign='$pcallsign'");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You can use PHP to emit JavaScript code, but you *cannot* use JavaScript to run PHP code without making a call back to the server, as in AJAX or a form POST. PHP runs *only* on the server, not in the client, so embedding JavaScript in your PHP makes no sense art all to PHP.

Comment: To fix this requires a bit more context. When is that supposed to get inserted?

Comment: All code included to see if it helps.

Comment: The problem is confused here. Like why can't you compute that value server-side using the `$_POST` value you apparently have on-hand? The trip through the browser is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines like `$ptimeflown = "<script>document.writeln(seconds);</script>";` are just junk code, that won't work. The only reason you "get" a value out of that is if you `echo` that into a document *and* run it in the browser, then you will get a `<script>` tag that gets evaluated, but this happens client-side.

You've script-injected your page, effectively.

As far as the server is concerned, `$ptimeflown` is just some random junk that when inserted into the database evaluates as (numerically) 0.

I'm supposing you can just flatten this out, remove the JavaScript excursion, and go with this:

```php
<?php
$times = explode(':', $_POST['ptimeflown']);
$ptimeflown = $times[0] * 60 * 60 + $times[1] * 60;
?>
```

Where `explode()` is the PHP equivalent of `split()`. Now you have a value you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
// STEP 1: Delete this block of code.
<script>
    var hms = '<?php echo $_POST['ptimeflown'];?>';
    var a = hms.split(':');
    var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60; 
</script>    

// STEP2: Replace the line of code below:
$ptimeflown = "<script>document.writeln(seconds);</script>";
// With the block below: (server-side processing)
$ptimeflown_raw = explode(":", $_POST['ptimeflown']);
$ptimeflown = ($ptimeflown_raw[0]*60*60)+($ptimeflown_raw[1]*60);

// STEP3: Use prepared statements instead. This is to avoid SQL injections.
// Replace the block of code below:
 mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO pendingflights (flight_number,callsign,departure,destination,fpm,distance,fuel_used,fuel_remaining,aircraft_reg,datetime,hoursflown,tracker_image,remarks,mp)
                              VALUES ('$pflight_number','$pcallsign','$pdeparture','$pdestination','0','$pdistance','0','0','$paircraft_reg','$pdate','$ptimeflown','$target_file','$premarks','1');");
        mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM bookedflights WHERE callsign='$pcallsign'");


// With the block below: (prepared statements)
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

$pendingflights_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO pendingflights(flight_number,callsign,departure,destination,fpm,distance,fuel_used,fuel_remaining,aircraft_reg,datetime,hoursflown,tracker_image,remarks,mp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
// Variable type assumptions made here.
$pendingflights_stmt->bind_param('isisidddsiisss', $pflight_number,$pcallsign,$pdeparture,$pdestination,'0',$pdistance,'0','0',$paircraft_reg,$pdate,$ptimeflown,$target_file,$premarks,'1');
$pendingflights_stmt->execute();
$pendingflights_stmt->close();

$bookedflights_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM bookedflights WHERE callsign=?");
// Variable type assumptions made here.
$bookedflights_stmt->bind_param('s', $pcallsign);
$bookedflights_stmt->execute();
$bookedflights_stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

*Addendum*

1. Make sure that the data type for `'hoursflown'` column in the `'pendingflights'` table is correct. Since you're sending the total seconds to the database, I would be assuming <s>'timestamp'</s> `int` as your data type.

Comment: Timestamp for total seconds?  No way.  It would either need to be a generic number data type (`int` or `float`), or a `time` data type (but that tends to be tricky to work with).

Comment: It is a ```int``` data type at the DB.

Comment: @Brilliand Oops!, my bad. Changed.